# Stable Matching Problem Worst Preference?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have one hundred pairs of women and men, and there is a man M that is ranked the second highest on every woman's preference rankings. Would it be possible that he ends up with the woman he least prefers on every single stable matching (men-optimal, women-optimal, etc.).

My intuition for this problem is that it is possible. If he is paired with his least preferred woman, that means every other pair (99 pairs) must be paired with their top choice. The left over women could prefer one of the other men over him, but the woman is his worst preference. Hence he could be paired with the worst choice. Could someone give a more elaborate proof?

Comment: The only problem with this proof seems to be the language. One hundred pairs of women and men is 200 persons altogether; and "every other pair" would then be 99 pairs, not 98. So I think you mean 100 total _persons,_ 50 of each sex to be matched in 50 opposite-sex pairs. After you match 98 people (49 pairs) to their top choices, _the_ leftover woman (who technically is "one of the leftover women," but we wouldn't say it that way when we know there's only one!) is matched with her second-choice man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the preference orderings are such that all $100$ women prefer this fellow second most.

There are $99$ other men. Pick randomly $99$ other women. Now, make it so that each of the $99$ men has a different favorite woman and that favorite woman also likes that man the best (they are "soulmates"- how sweet).

In any stable match, these soulmates will be paired. Otherwise they would leave their matched partners and find each other.

The remaining woman likes one of these $99$ men best, but she is our first-man's least favorite.

Since the $99$ pairs of soulmates are paired in every stable match, this woman and our first man must be paired in any stable match. Thus, although he is everyone's second favorite, he ends up with his least favorite.

Comment: awesome, this is basically what my answer is. thanks

Comment: Yep, looks like you had the right solution in mind.